# Apalike style with [author, year] in the beginning of my bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I'm using this code to get my bibliography printed with apalike style

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{memoir} 
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}

\cite{Web01}
\cite{Web02}
\cite{Web03}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{test}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

This code gives the following result
[image: What i got]

But i actually want a result like this one:
[image: the result that I want]

I want to get [author, year] before each reference, how can I do it with "apa" style?

Comment: The simple answer is "not easily" since this is *not* APA style, but closer to something like one of the `alpha` styles. But those styles tend to put the date last, so the two aren't really compatible with each other.

Comment: You mean the one I'm looking for is not an apa style? is there a style other than alpha that gives the [author, year] at the begining ? even if it's not APA style?

Comment: I vote to close this question as unclear since there is a misconception about APA style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default behaviour if no package for handling citations is loaded. It should be noted that this output is not correct and not APA. You get a proper APA bibiography if `natbib` is loaded.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mwepage}

\begin{document}

The following bibliography is not correct.~\cite{doody}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```